# Performance of modulus operator in C

Tags: c, modulo

From the execution time perspective, is using modulus operator more beneficial or the manual way of doing it if i am supposed to do the modulus thing a large number of times, about 10^6 times ?
Manually doing (number % mod_number) :

```
while(number >= mod_number) {
     number = number - mod_number;
}
```

Doing the same thing using % operator :

```
number = number % mod_number;
```

From what i have tested, manually doing it gives better time performance.
How is the modulus operator defined? I know the outputs for negative numbers are implementation defined, i am asking about the working of the operator, i.e., its complexity so that i can justify the better manual performance.
**Note :** The question is specifically for implementation in C.
The code snippet:

```
for (j = 0; j < idx; j++) {
            num = mark[j];
            dif = k - num;
            if (dif < 0) dif = (-1 * dif) + 100;
            many = count[num];
            prev = ap[dif][k];
            ap[dif][k] = ap[dif][k] + ap[dif][num];
            //the manual way here works faster than %
            if (ap[dif][k] >= mod) ap[dif][k] -= mod;
            ap[dif][k] += many;
            if (ap[dif][k] >= mod) ap[dif][k] -= mod;
            sum = (sum + ap[dif][k]);
            if (sum >= mod) sum -= mod;
            sum = sum - prev;
}
```

The above loop is executed 2*(10^5)*t times with 'idx' gradually increasing till 100 for each 't'. Used t = 10.

Comment: won't that be compiler/implementation dependent?

Comment: also: please show your benchmarking code....

Comment: Did you measure it? How does the first snippet run faster in average? Take the case like INT_MAX % 3, how many times you need to subtract compare to the simple division?

Answer (score 4):

I would be very surprised if the loop were more efficient when `number` is many times larger than `mod_number`. Any CPU you're likely to use has a built-in division operation that returns both the quotient and the remainder in constant time, and this will be used to implement the `%` operator. Your loop takes `O(number/mod_number)` time.

I suggest you take a look at the generated assembly code for the two versions and you'll see this.

Comment: If the CPU's division is constant time, then so is O(number/mod_number). Because apparently `number` is bounded by a constant.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the implementation. It is pointless to discuss performance without a given system in mind.

The modulus operator will likely be implemented through the CPU's division instruction, which on most CPUs is relatively slow in comparison to other CPU instructions. However, it seems highly unlikely that a loop like the one in your example will be more efficient.

More likely, the performance difference you are experiencing is either related to wrong optimization settings or incorrect benchmarking.

Answer (score 0):

According to my experience, using the modulus operator should give you better performance. The people who have written C compilers should have considered the optimization of the operation they are performing.

But your test results shows the other away, it may depend on the code you have written. It would be easier to find why? if you show your code...

Answer (score 0):

The example you have shown (not that `while` loop at the top, the snippet at the bottom) is a case where the "divisor" is only subtracted at most once. That is essentially the one case in which "repeated" subtraction (0 or 1 times, a special case of repeated subtraction) can be (and commonly is, but not *necessarily*) faster than division-based modulo. Obviously it depends on how fast division is on the target, how fast a test/branch (or test/predicated instruction) is on the target, and in the case of branches it even depends on how predictable the branch will be.

A compiler is unlikely to make that optimization (but it's not impossible), because it only makes sense if it is known that the subtraction will only happen at most once (or perhaps more than one, if division is especially slow on the target, but some lowish bound is still needed), which is in general a hard thing to find out for a compiler.

To give some [real life numbers](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf), on a Haswell 32bit signed division (and therefore also modulo) would take 22 to 29 cycles, and a branch misprediction might take up to 20 cycles, but that's a worst case and the branch should not be mispredicted all the time. Also, you could avoid the branch (if it's badly predicted) and do something like this (not tested, just to give you some idea)

```
sub eax, edx
lea edx, [eax + edx]
cmovl eax, edx
```

Which should only take about 4 cycles, independent of any predictability. Using a branch may be faster if it can be predicted well.